Audio Amplifier ICs with RC Filters
Hopefully my questions aren't too simple or vague, and will be helpful to anyone else looking for similar information as I am right now.
My electrical engineering knowledge is mostly a hobby/self-taught. I bought 3 different audio-specific amplifier ICs to play around with (LM386, TDA2050, and LM3886) and have had success building circuits to play music from my phone through wired up component speakers (a midrange and tweeter), including logarithmic potentiometers as volume control.
I just bought a component subwoofer to test with and wanted to try including a low-pass filter to limit the frequencies being passed to the speaker, but I have a few questions regarding this.
Below is the circuit diagram I followed from the TDA2050's Datasheet:

The TDA2050 Datasheet can be found here:
I believe I should put the filter after the amp, as I don't want to have to use a different amp for each speaker when I try using a woofer + mid + tweeter. Would it not be as simple as adding an RC filter like so?

If I understand, the 1,000uF Capacitor (C7) is a coupling capacitor that somehow brings out the bass. I'm not sure exactly how this works but I assume I should leave that there.
This seems simple enough to me, but everything in electronics is complicated and I have a few questions about this. The impedance of the speaker is only 4 ohms, adding a resistor in series with the speaker would significantly impact the dB of the signal that was just amplified, wouldn't it? Something in my gut tells me that's very undesirable.
My second thought was that maybe I should just try to pick the smallest resistor value I can to minimize the voltage drop over the resistor, but if I choose a very low value resistor (lets say, 10 ohms rather than a value like 1k or higher), then I run into the problem of potentially having a lot of current being pushed through the resistor (The datasheets seem to say the LM386 has a maximum power output around 1W, but the TDA2050 and LM3886 are up to a few dozen Watts). I'm assuming the simple 1/4 Watt hobby resistors I have sitting around would not take that very well.
Do the questions I have around this seem to make sense? I'm thinking if my logic is sound on how to incorporate the Low Pass filter after the amplifier, then maybe I just need to order some resistors with higher wattage ratings. But before ordering more things to test with I figured I'd post and ask if I'm on the right track or not.
I do plan on trying to also do a High Pass and Band Pass filter eventually for a tweeter and mid-range speaker, but I'm beginning with the woofer. I'm assuming that, with appropriate capacitors and resistors, having one amplifier feed 3 sets of filters and speakers is okay.
To try and summarize my questions:

Is my idea of simply adding a resistor and capacitor like I boxed in green correct?
Should I try to make the resistor used in the RC filter as small as possible to minimize the voltage drop?
If I use the RC filter like shown, should I order resistors with a wattage rating based on the output power of the amplifiers?


None of these three are operational amplifiers; they are audio power amplifiers (and pretty old ones); operational amplifiers are different things :)

Thanks guys for your informative answers, they're just what I was looking for. I'll mark my question as answered and summarize my takeaways from your posts: 1) I was well aware of Crossovers and my intention was pretty much to make my own filters to act like a crossover would, but Crossovers are built with Inductor based filters which are not substitutable with just RC filters like I was thinking. I've been reading a book on Electronics, and if I remember correctly, Inductors generate electromagnetic fields when the current flowing through their windings increases or decreases. This electromag

@ChrisHansen The answer box is only for answers, please use the comment system for discussion thanks

The output of the TDA2050 or LM386 will be centered about half way between the two supplies, 0V and \$V_S\$ in this case. In other words, the potential of the output is about \$\frac{V_S}{2}\$ on average, oscillating above and below that average. The purpose of C7 is to remove that DC offset, so that the speaker sees a voltage oscillating around 0V. Without C7, the speaker would have a huge and permanent DC current flowing through it, which is bad for many reasons. C7 does not enhance bass; on the contrary, C7 is made deliberately large to avoid altering the amplitude of any frequency component in the audio spectrum.
If you place a resistance in series with the speaker, it will of course attenuate the signal arriving at the speaker, since the pair of resistances will form a voltage divider. If for example added resistance is \$R=4\Omega\$, the same as the speaker's own resistance, then the amplitude (voltage) across the speaker will be halved, and power (being proportional to the square of voltage) will be 25%. The added resistance will also be dissipating power, and getting hot. Placing an RC filter between the power amplifier and the speaker could work, but it is inefficient.
Typically the only reason to place filters between the power amplifier and speakers are when you wish to "route" certain bands of the audio spectrum to different speakers, tweeter, mid-range and woofer, for example. In those cases though, the filters are built using inductors and capacitors, to avoid the energy losses associated with resistance. Your RC filter doesn't really fit with this model. It is also important for those filters to block DC (using series capacitance like C7), so that multiple connected speakers do not present less than 4Ω (in this case) DC load in total. Again, your RC filter is not suitable in this respect.
My advice is to build or buy a separate power amplifier for the sub-woofer, and performing filtering prior to that stage.


I believe I should put the filter after the amp, as I don't want to have to use a different amp for each speaker when I try using a woofer + mid + tweeter.

In the speaker world, that's called a cross-over.

Would it not be as simple as adding an RC filter like so?

Not really! in that, the resistor would convert all the energy that doesn't go through the filter to heat. But you want that energy to go to other speakers, so an RC filter won't do. Typical cross-over filters are LC filters (or RLC, if the parasitics don't suffice to dampen resonance, but that's leading too far here).



If I understand, the 1,000uF Capacitor (C7) is a coupling capacitor that somehow brings out the bass. I'm not sure exactly how this works but I assume I should leave that there.

No, that's an AC coupling capacitor. It's there because the output of the amplifier IC can only be a positive voltage (relative to the ground pin), and you need the voltage across the speaker to swing in both ways.

The impedance of the speaker is only 4 ohms,

Nice speakers! Your amplifier ICs are designed to drive speakers with impedances that low, but at least the first one will sound bad:
 The LM386's output distortion "explodes" at powers higher than 0.2 W. You're trying to drive a speaker that was probably meant for powers > 10 W, so "acceptably distorted" and "loud enough to hear" will be mutually exclusive.
(really, all these three amplifier ICs are obsolete, but you're probably not expecting to get sound like you would get from a commercial hifi deck, so you're probably fine with that. Forget about the LM386, though.)

The impedance of the speaker is only 4 ohms, adding a resistor in series with the speaker would significantly impact the dB of the signal that was just amplified, wouldn't it?

Yep! That's why speaker cables tend to be thick: much copper = low resistance.
Anyways, don't do RC, and you'll be fine. There's a lot of online stuff about building cross-overs :)
To answer your summarized questions:

Is my idea of simply adding a resistor and capacitor like I boxed in green correct?

No, don't do it. If you only drive a single voice coil (i.e., a single speaker), filter at amplifier input; else, build an LC cross-over.

Should I try to make the resistor used in the RC filter as small as possible to minimize the voltage drop?

No, because then you'd need a very large capacitor, you'd convert a lot of power to heat, and it's still not the right architecture.

If I use the RC filter like shown, should I order resistors with a wattage rating based on the output power of the amplifiers?

see above.

Unrequested advice, do ignore if not helpful:
From my perspective, you're honestly going the "hard route" by going for these rather old amplifier ICs. For four reasons:

for commercial reasons, it's easier to find good documentation on newer chips from the people that build these. That entails datasheets with better-explained circuits, and demoboards whose schematics you are encouraged to copy and modify.
a modern switching amplifier with a bridge output will be able to produce the same amount of power at its output at less than half the supply voltage. Meaning that with far less effort on the supply side, you get better results. And: you don't need to mount a heatsink already for low output powers.
The only one of the three amplifiers that you chose that doesn't introduce a (by modern standards) unacceptable amount of distortion is the LM3886. If your own acoustic satisfaction is relevant (might not be the case at all, if this is experimentation!), the usual "sounds OK" threshold for the THD+N (total harmonic distortion of the output, plus added noise) is somewhere better than between 0.1 % and 0.5 % THD+N (the more esoterically audiophile people you ask, the lower that number gets; it's really not that relevant for human consumption, it's more an easy metric to measure and put in a datasheet, but you do hear the catastrophic 4% THD that the TDA2050 delivers starting at half its rated output power. Forget about the LM386.), and you do hear noise in silent passages, so check the datasheet of any amplifier IC you consider for the figure from which you can read "at a load of 4 Ω, at so-and-so-many W output, for a tone of this and that frequency I get ABC% THD+N" and make sure it's low enough for you.
modern amplifier ICs are simpler to use. Your TDA2050 circuitry needs 12 external passive components to work. 12! For a single channel! The LM3886, which I'd consider the only part worthwhile in your selection, needs a dual supply and/or complex external compensation to sound well. But it's in a very well-handleable package, so it does have that going for it (modern efficient amplifier ICs for these powers tend to be flat and have small pin pitch, to allow for better layout and better cooling in compact devices).


The exact problem is because you seem to think the low pass filter belongs between amplifier and speaker.
Sure, some speakers (not the elements/drivers) but finished products can have LC filters as crossovers between elements and resistors to balance the loudness between elements of different sensitivity.
But if you just want to have bass management for e.g. 2.1 stereo setup, you just low pass filter the bass to it's own channel and high pass filter the satellites, and then amplify the result into speakers.
So,

No, not correct or good idea, do it before amplification

and 3) No need to consider due to 1)


